# Poetry: how to run script during poetry install

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have to download some things for nltk and I add it into one script

```
import nltk


nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

So is it possible to run it during `poetry install`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Poetry does not officially support any post install script.